# Saving R object canceled for file size reasons?

Tags: r

I ran a Bayesian regression on a large, messy health dataset recently, a longitudinal mixed effects model with random slopes and nested intercepts (encounters within clients). As a result I have an R have object that is comfortably larger than anything I have used before: 7722886880 bytes (7.7 gig!)

When I tried to save this object as an RData file it took a long time to save and then failed, with the error

```
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'fooFolder/fooSubFolder/foo.RData', probable reason 'Operation canceled'
```

Which I assume means 'file's too big cowboy'. Does anyone know a way to allow me to save the object? It took a *long* time to run the model and k-fold validation. I'd rather not do it all again.

Comment: What is the structure of the object?  If it's basically a dataframe, then save the first half in one file, the second half in another file.  Or thirds, or tenths...

Comment: It's a brms object and has *lot* of different elements under the hood. I was wondering if there is any way to change some settings in R that allow for saving larger files without timing out (which I assume is what's happening here). But you may be right that the only way to save it is to decompose the object into different elements. Unquestionably the element creating the problem will be the stored dataframe with the parameter estimates. Maybe I need to head to the stan forums for this one.

Comment: If it is something like stored MCMC results, then you probably don't lose much by storing only every 10th entry.  They are likely highly correlated.

Comment: Not sure, but R needs contiguous memory available for some operations, so it’s possible that a necessary intermediate could not be created.

Comment: Have you tried it with `bzfile` or `xzfile`?

Comment: @CPB I'm not sure what those are

Comment: Already tried using `saveRDS()`? You should set `compress=FALSE` then, and `readRDS()` will read significantly faster such large files.

Comment: 7.7 GB isn't *that*  large ...

Comment: There's a cran packaged `butcher` intended to let you `weigh` bloated model files, and choose how to cut them down. Also for general file saving needs, `qs` package is an excellent choice

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf, that worked. You are right Roland, although 8 gig is large for me I figured it wasn't *that* large.